# Can I have a feedback about my Postgres performance?

Tags: postgresql, query-optimization

this is the query I performed in pgAdmin4:

```
update point
set grid_id_new=g.grid_id
from grid as g 
where (point.region='EMILIA-ROMAGNA'and st_within(point.geom,g.geom))
```

`Point` is a 34 millions record table describing a point geometry (16 GB - 20 columns)

`Grid` is a 10 millions record table describing a multlipolygon geometry (grid) (4 GB)

I want my point table to associate with the grid ID they lie in. The query output are 2.5 million records updated (since I filter by region), in 24 minutes.

I feel like it took too much time.

These are my computer specifics:

> Windows 10 PRO/Intel(R) Core(TM) i9-10920X CPU @ 3.50 GHz/RAM 128 GB/953GB SSD(C)+3.4TB HDD(F)

I have installed Postgres13 and the data folder is on F (I know this may be wrong so I am planning to move it).

I have also tried to tune postgres.conf file but I got poor results.

Can someone please explain if my Postgres performance are as poor as I think? And, if so, how can I make it better? Also, what could be a good configuration for postgres.conf according with my hardware?

Update
@jjanes Hi there! it took 8 minutes to run the query you wrote, and this is the result:

```
QUERY PLAN

Gather  (cost=1363.89..273178616690.49 rows=23057026760 width=28) (actual time=76.935..503830.684 rows=2335279 loops=1)
  Workers Planned: 2
  Workers Launched: 2
  Buffers: shared hit=18634521 read=2426823
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=363.89..270872913014.49 rows=9607094483 width=28) (actual time=157.628..503021.991 rows=778426 loops=3)

        Buffers: shared hit=18634521 read=2426823
        ->  Parallel Seq Scan on egon_geom_new  (cost=0.00..2657488.69 rows=1064319 width=59) (actual time=1.575..8642.488 rows=855390 loops=3)
              Filter: (dsxreg = 'EMILIA-ROMAGNA'::text)
              Rows Removed by Filter: 10581246
              Buffers: shared hit=259223 read=2225262
        ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on "6_emilia_grid"  (cost=363.89..254491.98 rows=903 width=148) (actual time=0.573..0.573 rows=1 loops=2566171)
              Filter: st_within((egon_geom_new.geom_new)::geometry, geom)
              Heap Blocks: exact=784879
              Buffers: shared hit=18375298 read=201561
              ->  Bitmap Index Scan on emilia_idx  (cost=0.00..363.66 rows=9027 width=0) (actual time=0.283..0.283 rows=1 loops=2566171)
                    Index Cond: (geom ~ (egon_geom_new.geom_new)::geometry)
                    Buffers: shared hit=16167046 read=74534
Planning:
  Buffers: shared hit=130 read=3 dirtied=2
Planning Time: 22.756 ms
Execution Time: 504042.609 ms
```

Thanks!

Comment: How long does it take to select the same data, without the update?  `explain (analyze, buffers) select point.id, g.grid_id from point, grid g where point.region='EMILIA-ROMAGNA'and st_within(point.geom,g.geom)`

Comment: @jjanes I will tell you for sure in a couple of days but I can guess from previous experiences that the query 'select point.id, g.grid_id...' as you wrote would take a couple of minutes. Generally speaking the update query are the slowest. Anyway I will reply you in a couple of days with the precise answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a GiST index on one of the `geometry` columns, that will speed up the nested loop join.  But you cannot use another join strategy, because the join condition is not using the equality operator (`=`), so it will always be slow to join two big tables.

Comment: Thanks for answering @Laurenz! I did it, I created a GiST index on both geometry columns, but still. I just don't understand if the time it takes is right for my hardware specifics or there is a bottleneck somewhere!

Comment: That has nothing to do with your hardware. Looping millions of times takes a while. Could you come up with a faster method?